# Unable to Open the onedrive Excel file using VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel file on onedrive location and I have written a function first to replace the "/" with "\" in the file sharepoint path.
However I am trying to open the file using below syntax, but unable to open

```
Set objLogExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")

Set objLogWorkbook = objLogExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open(path,False,False)
```

The above line is adding .xlsx extension in the file path, any suggestion ?

Comment: `Set objLogExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")` - that's a weird way to try to go about it... normally you just create an Excel *application*.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way, please:

1. Firstly, manually open the workbook in discussion;

   In the open workbook VBE put the next code, in any module:

   `Sub testFullName()
      Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.FullName
   End Sub`

In this way you will have the online characteristic full name. Something like this: `"https://d.docs.live.net/fdb7a15aac1d9134/TestWorkbook.xlsx"`.

2. Copy the above full name **like it is** and put it in the next `Sub`:

   `Sub testOpenWBOneDrive()
      Dim wbFullName, objLogExcel As Object
      Set objLogExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      objLogExcel.Visible = True 
      wbFullName = "https://d.docs.live.net/fdb7a15aac1d9134/TestWorkbook.xlsx"
      objLogExcel.Workbooks.Open (wbFullName)
   End Sub`

Of course, you must replace the example full path with yours, obtained as explained above...

Edited: In order to be able to use the code for both cases (Online - Offline) you have to proceed in the next way:

1. Determine if an internet connection exists:

Copy, please the next function declaration on top of your module (in the declarations area):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetConnectedState Lib "wininet.dll" _
                            (ByRef dwflags As Long, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long
```

Use the next function in that module:

```
Private Function isInternetConON() As Boolean
  isInternetConON = InternetGetConnectedState(0&, 0&)
End Function
```

Then, use the next code to deal with OneDrive workbook opening, even offline:

```
Private Sub testOpenOneDriveOnlineOffline()
  Dim sfilename As String, Xl As Object, xlsheet As Object
  sfilename = "https://d.docs.live.net/fdb7a15aac1d9134/Test.xlsm"
 Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ' or Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")
     Xl.Visible = True

  If isInternetConON Then
    Set xlsheet = Xl.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=sfilename, ReadOnly:=False)
 Else
    'In case of internet connection beeing down:
    'Note: It works only if you uncheck:
    'OneDrive -> More -> Settings -> Office "Use Office applications to sync Office files that I open!
    Dim sLocalODPath As String
    sLocalODPath = Environ("onedrive") & "\" 'If your workbook is not in the OneDrive folder root,
                                             'you have to add the other folder(s), to build the path
    sfilename = Right(sfilename, Len(sfilename) - InStrRev(sfilename, "/")) ': Debug.Print sfilename: Stop
    Set xlsheet = Xl.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=sLocalODPath & sfilename, ReadOnly:=False)
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Abhishek Jain: OK. But are you able now to open it in (local) Excel? Another question: Is your `OneDrive` folder synchronized? If yes, you can also try opening the workbook locally, (automatically) determining the local folder path...

Comment: @Abhishek Jain: Now, I can see that you deleted your comment and in these circumstances, mine looks strange (at least)...

Comment: I have a file on onedrive and I want to access that file and data into it with my logic

Comment: @Abhishek Jain: I have nothing against any logic! But, did you try my code, **only to check if the solution works**? Then, you may optimize it in your way, using any logic, I would say... And I asked you about the synchronization. If your `OneDrive` folder is synchronized, I can post another simple variant to open the workbook in discussion. At least when internet connection is down... And synchronization will be done after internet starts working.

Comment: Yes my Onedrive folder is synchronised

Comment: @Abhishek Jain: We are making some progress... Now you confirmed the synchronization. About testing the solution I provided, still nothing... I will edit my answer and add a new version, able do deal with both OneDrive locations (Cloud and Local). Maybe, in the meantime, you will finish your logic to use it...