# Workbook.open stops the VBA code after the workbook opens

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am trying to copy paste some data from one workbook to another this is my code:

```
 Sub get_data()
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim wn As Worksheet
 Dim lastrow

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Open the other workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\OneDrive - My Smart Place\Reception\Shared 
Reception Files\Misc\data.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("data")
Set wn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Helper Sheet")

With ws

   lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   wn.Unprotect Password:=pass

.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 5)).Copy _
    Destination:=wn.Range("A1")

wn.Protect Password:=pass

End With

'Close the workbook from which we just got some data and make sure not to save it in case 
'accidental changes were made to it.
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

When the code reaches this line

```
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rec135\OneDrive\OneDrive - My Smart Place\Reception\Shared 
 Reception Files\Misc\data.xlsx")
```

The code stops running like the sub has ended. I was watching closely to Project tab on the left and it those appear that excel tries to open the file, however it closes automatically and stops running any code.

Any help with this would be appreciated

Comment: It looks strange... Can you manually open the respective workbook copying *C:\Users\rec135\OneDrive\OneDrive - My Smart Place\Reception\Shared 
 Reception Files\Misc\data.xlsx* in windows explorer and pressing `Enter`? Anyhow, if the path is problematic, the code should raise an error. But maybe it is something wrong with your settings handling errors...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes the workbook opens if I type that in my explorer. 
I also don't get any error message when this occurs.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try replacing either file with something clean to rule out issues like corrupt files. If that doesn't help, try a different file path.

Comment: Try modifying this line `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in `Application.ScreenUpdating = Falset` and run the code. Does it stop highlighting the respective code line? I am trying to find out if your installation has a problem with handling (all) errors... And, please confirm that the workbook in discussion is not open, as I could understand.

Comment: I remember something about a bug in EXCEL VBA, which stops the code when try opening a workbook if Shift is pressed... But it was some year ago and I do not think Microsoft did not solve it. I will search for such a page I could see some year before, even if I do not think this can be the problem in your case.  Do you run the code pressing a keys combination? Edited: I found it [here](https://jkp-ads.com/articles/workbookopenbug.asp)...

Comment: @FaneDuru if I comment that line and run the code I actually see the other workbook being open and closed and the code still stops at that line.
I only am pressing "F8" to go through the code

Comment: Which "that line"?

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` on top of the module running the code? If not, what I suggested above was not the most appropriate... Your VBA may 'think' that `Falset` is a variable and if it does not have any value `Falset` of `False` is the same... Try modifying it as `Application.ScreenUpdatings = False`. Added an extra `s`...

Comment: I just did some more testing: - Closed excel all together ran the code and it worked. Then tried running a second time and got the error again. Second test, closed excel all together open both files, closed second file than ran the code and got the error. I think it is something to do with how excel is closing files

Comment: I did " 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False as a comment.
If I run falset or falses the code says that "falset" is not a declared variable
I do have option explicit

Comment: What does "got the error again" mean? You say something about not error... Aren't you referring to VBA error? Do you meant the code stopped (without error)?

Comment: Try your code but opening a local file. Maybe something like `C:\Temp\test.xlsx`. If it works with a normal file, then try copying your original file into same temp folder and run the code again. If it works there, could be something related to security settings in One Drive.

Comment: "Got the error again" was meant as the macro stop running when the workbook try to open. I am not getting error messages, but the code is not running when it tries to open the second workbook. If I close excel, it apparently runs, however only once.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes apparently this is some kind of onedrive issue. as the issue only happens when it is with a onedrive file. I wonder how to get around this as I checked my onedrive settings and they all look fine

Comment: One way to work around would be using VBA to copy the file to a location where you can execute the code, do whatever you need and copyback into Onedrive, overwriting existing file. [CopyFile method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfile-method) Also, check [this answer. It may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61914157/unable-to-open-the-onedrive-excel-file-using-vba-code) but not tested because I don't have One Drive.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I might have to look at another solution as Copyfile method is not finding the file in onedrive. And the other thing about onedrive is not working well when I try. but thanks for the ideas

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I finally was able to open the document using your answer to open opendrive documents. How can I reference it? the program is not letting me do `code set  wb = testOpenWBOneDrive `

Comment: @Believe82 Glad to hear. You should edit your question with this new info, add the code that is working for you and now explain the new problem you got. Or maybe open a different question to solve this new problem (is better to have just 1 problem in each question). We need to see the new code that works and how to fix the new issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code from

[Unable to Open the onedrive Excel file using VBA Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61914157/unable-to-open-the-onedrive-excel-file-using-vba-code)

And thanks to comments about how to find the location of my file on one drive (recording a macro)

I was able to open the file.

Thanks to all that commented.

Answer (score 0):

try using `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Environ("OneDriveConsumer") & "\OneDrive - My Smart Place\Reception\Shared  Reception Files\Misc\data.xlsx")` if you are using onedrive business try replacing 'onedriveconsumer' with `OneDrive` or `OneDriveCommercial`

Comment: I tried this and received error 1004 that excel couldn't find the file. It does point to the right address, but it can't find the file even though it is there.
I am using onedrive business and did try both options you said with same result

Comment: @Believe82 in windows explorer when you click the onedrive section try creating a new folder in that main section and copy your file there then try the 3 options `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Environ("OneDriveConsumer") & "\NewFolder\data.xlsx")` -- `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Environ("OneDrive") & "\NewFolder\data.xlsx")` -- `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Environ("OneDriveCommercial") & "\NewFolder\data.xlsx")`

Comment: @Believe82 also try recording a macro in excel manually opening the file navigating to the path mentioned in `OneDrive - My Smart Place\Reception\Shared 
 Reception Files\Misc\data.xlsx` using the dialog box then after opening the file stop the recording then navigate to the macro to see how it opened the file

Comment: @Believe82 try also using this `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rec135\OneDrive - My Smart Place\Reception\Shared 
Reception Files\Misc\data.xlsx")`

Comment: @Believe82 i cant see the setup of onedrive files in your pc so i cant test but on my side i can open a onedrive file with this `Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\[myusername]\OneDrive\Documents\data1.xlsx")
End Sub
` i copied the location by right clicking the file in windows explorer select properties then looking at the location